# Bind a key for multiple units to use the same spell

Tags: dota-2

Is there a way for me to bind a key that will allow multiple units in my control group to all use the same spell at once?

For example, if I have 3 centaurs as chen, and I have them all selected. Can I press one key to make them all warstomp at the same time?

Or if I have 3 familiars as Visage. When I have all three selected, is there a button I can press to have them all stun at the same time?

Comment: isn't there a "global order" command with ctrl ? Doesn't that allow you to stun with all 3 centaurs at the same time ? If no then im affraid its not possible because even when you have a group of units sselected the skills are individual and you must scroll throuh the units to make them all stun

Comment: Im not sure, but i press tab w, tab w, tab, w. in quick succession, for example. tab will cycle through selected units. and w will of course cast.

Comment: @WizLiz yeah that is something I am looking for. And if it currently doesn't exist, I am pretty sure you can make a bind for it in console, just like how those other guys made a return to base bind even though that isn't built into the game

Comment: I know it is possible, but I just don't know the code to write for it in console. If there is an attack bind that tells all units in your selected group to attack, there has to be a way to also yo make all your selected units cast a spell.

Comment: @krikara the "Global order" thing already exsits in the game, that's what im saying, search in the settings.

Comment: if someone finds it, definitely write an answer to the question...this would up my meepo skillz so much

Comment: i will write that for you after work. should be quite easy with dota_ability_execute1 till 3 for the unitspells after tabcommanding. the difficult part is that doing many things at once is kinda blocked by valve. i try to circumvent that by seperating command"blocks", first part on buttonpress(down) and second on buttonrelease(up)

Comment: @krikara i finished my script with a little extra. if you are satisfied consider marking it as the right answer!

Comment: @Wandang Heh, no problem. I was waiting for you to create this monster :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built a few variants of your desired script:

## Preamble:

```
alias "Qdefault" "dota_ability_execute 0"
```

I did this because it is more readable for me. If you don't want to use that alias you need to change `Qdefault` below to `dota_ability_execute 0` !

### Hero + 3 units in 1 group:

Assumes that you selected your hero + units (in this case 3x familiars) and switches to the first, casts a spell and switches to the next until it reaches to the hero again.

```
alias "heroAndUnits" "dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected;"
```

### Unit selected

Like the first but starts at the first familiar

```
alias "unitSelected" "Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected;"
```

### Only units

Group of units only

```
alias "unitsOnly" "Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected;"
```

### Manually

This script switches to the next unit and uses a spell. This enables you to time your stuns (chainstun) the enemy.

```
alias "manually" "dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault"
```

## Final binding

You need to bind any of those aliases (you can have them all in your exec file, aliases wont be executed if not used/binded!)

```
bind "B" "heroAndUnits"
```

## Afterword:

Those scripts (execpt "manually") assume that the group consist of 3 units. I did not find a way to count the units of a group. Otherwise i may be able to adjust that script a bit.

## Extra:

Additionally i wrote a script that lets you cycle through a script from above (in this case heroAndUnits1-4) depending on your unitcount! Feel free to ask me about it since this is pretty advanced.

```
alias "heroAndUnits1" "dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected"
alias "heroAndUnits2" "dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected"
alias "heroAndUnits3" "dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected;"
alias "heroAndUnits4" "dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected; Qdefault; dota_cycle_selected;"

alias groupSpellToggle "oneUnit" 
alias oneUnit "bind B heroAndUnits1; say_team "Script for 1 unit selected";  alias groupSpellToggle twoUnit" 
alias twoUnit "bind B heroAndUnits2; say_team "Script for 2 units selected"; alias groupSpellToggle threeUnit"
alias threeUnit "bind B heroAndUnits3; say_team "Script for 3 units selected"; alias groupSpellToggle fourUnit"
alias fourUnit "bind B heroAndUnits4; say_team "Script for 4 units selected"; alias groupSpellToggle oneUnit"

bind "N" groupSpellToggle
```

Pressing N in this case cycles through heroAndUnits1-4 and then back to 1.
Each cycle rebinds "B" (you can change this if you want) to execute the groupspell.

To realize which number is currently active as a user i added a `say_team` which is a normal ingame-chat to your teammates.